# Eclipse, plugin preference loading issue

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have trouble getting preference loaded on to eclipse. I am not able to load the value for the preference without going to the preference page first.
I start eclipse, use my plugin, i see that the feature is not enabled.
I start eclipse, go to preference page and the use my plugin, all works fine.

I am trying to access the value for enable from preference store using the below code

```
final IPreferenceStore preferences = new ScopedPreferenceStore(new InstanceScope(), <my plugin id>);
this.enabled = preferences.getBoolean(<templateName>_ENABLE_TEMPLATE"));
```

this call goes to method
    public boolean getBoolean(String name) {
        String value = internalGet(name);
        return value == null ? BOOLEAN_DEFAULT_DEFAULT : Boolean.valueOf(value)
                .booleanValue();
    }
    internalGet(name) -- returns null..as a result `this.enabled` is set to `false`.

in my code i check this variable and if it is false i display an error message and don't proceed further.

I want to know how we can make sure that the preferences are enabled/loaded as soon as they are invoked.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Before you can read a value from preference store, someone has to write the value into it. I assume that the preference page sets that value, but is there some other place in code where you store the value of "<templateName>_ENABLE_TEMPLATE"? Do you perhaps clean the workspace before each launch and preferences are deleted?

Comment: Hi,  I am trying to access the preference values at the time of initialization (immediately after initialization)  of preference page. Is it right to do that way?

Answer (score 1):

Preferences service is initialized when `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plugin is activated, meaning that it is virtually impossible for your code to access it in uninitialized state. The reason for not getting the value of a preference is that the value has not been set.

It is also possible to specify defaults for all your preferences using *preferences.ini* file (should be placed in the plugin/bundle root).